# 500 Error when using ajax to get json data

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use an ajax call to get json data about my model from my controller. I know 500 error could mean lots of things but I would like to eliminate the possibility of simple error by me.

Console gives me error of: `500 Internal Service Error`.
Otherwise I can access it in the url just fine but I don't get anything in the console.

**Index.cshtml**

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("dataTransfer", "Data")",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    getData();
}, 10000);
```

**DataController**

```
public JsonResult dataTransfer()
{
    string DataProvider = "Sample";

    var model = from d in db.Data
                where d.Name == DataProvider
                select d;

    return Json(model);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

500 internal error means your server code is failing, running into an exception because of bad code !

From your code, i can see a problem which could be the cause of your error.

When returning Json from a GET action method, you need to pass `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet` as the second parameter of `Json` method.

```
public JsonResult dataTransfer()
{
    string DataProvider = "Sample";

    var model = from d in db.Data
                where d.Name == DataProvider
                select d;

    return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Usually in an ASP.NET MVC application, the **GET** method's are supposed to be returning a view and typically the **POST** method does some processing on the posted form data/ajax data and return a response, which can be ***JSON***. But if you really want to return Json data from your GET action method, You have to explicitly specify that using the above method we did

*Ofcourse, Web API's has a different concept (And implementation behind the scene)*