# How can I access the data passed back to an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, generic-list

Now that I'm successfully calling my controller method from Ajax now (see Update 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782122/how-can-i-determine-the-cause-of-the-internal-server-error-resulting-from-my-aja) for the specifics), my next step is to access the data passed back from the Controller method in the Ajax success function.

In this case, I'm passing back a jsonified generic list of string (0..N string vals).

How can I access them from the success function embedded in the jquery ajax call:

```
var model = JSON.stringify({ unit: unitval, report: rptval });
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitReportPairEmailAddresses", "UnitReportPair")',
    data: { unit: unitval, report: rptval }, // data: model,
    contentType: 'application/json', //<= this is paired with stringify above; if comment out one, comment out both
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
        alert(result.data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('failure');
    }
});
```

I assume it's by querying the "result" object, but how? I tried this:

```
success: function (result) {
    alert('success');
    alert(result[0]);
},
```

...but only saw an "undefined" alert after the "success" alert. A simple "alert(result)" showed nothing, as did "alert(result.data)"

The Controller (in the test case scenario) is passing back a single string, an email address. In "real life" usage, it will be 0..N email addresses, but for now it is successfully passing back one string, yet it is either not in "result" for some reason, or I am not getting it out of there as it should be extracted.

### UPDATE

Okay, now we're getting somewhere; I put a breakpoint in the "success" function, hovered over its "returneddata" param, and saw:

[image]

Yet when I then added this code to the "success" callback:

```
success: function (returneddata) {
    alert('success');
    alert(UnitReportPairEmailVals[0]);
},
```

(replacing "returneddata" with "UnitReportPairEmailVals" which is the value of returneddata), on stepping into the second alert I got "Uncaught reference error: 'UnitReportPairEmailVals' is not defined"

### UPDATE 2

Once I pieced together several different answers, I wrote up a tip on how to do this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1095263/Minimalistic-Example-of-Sending-and-Receiving-Data).

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, what is the value of `result`?

Comment: It doesn't let me step into the method - I can place a breakpoint at the start of the AJAX method, but F10 takes me all the way to the end of it. F11 takes me into the labyrinthine quagmire of jquery itself.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint inside the callback and it's never hit, then the callback isn't being invoked at all.

Comment: It is, because I see the "success" alert. Oh, I see what you mean - I did hit when I put a breakpoint there; it seems odd to me that a breakpoint at the start of it, and then hitting F10, didn't take me into it.

Comment: Then you can place a breakpoint to stop the debugger there and examine the runtime value of `result`.  We can't really guess what the structure of `result` is, but you can examine it.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - **returneddata.** UnitReportPairEmailVals[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught reference error: 'UnitReportPairEmailVals' is not defined

*By itself* it isn't defined anywhere.  It's not a variable, it's a property on a variable.  Specifically, on `returneddata`.  Variables here essentially work the same way as they do in C#:

```
function (returneddata) {
    alert(returneddata.UnitReportPairEmailVals[0]);
}
```